# Custom exception class throws compile-time error

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to create my own exception, which extends the Exception class, but when I try to throw it, the compiler throws a compile-time error.

Here is my exception class:

```
package Exception;

public class notAdultException extends Exception {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ("you are not adult");
    }
}
```

Here is where I try to throw the exception:

```
int Age = 16;
try {
    if (Age < 18) {
        throw new notAdultException();
}
catch (notAdultException t) {
    System.out.println(t);
}
```

And here is the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
        No exception of type notAdultException can be thrown; an exception type must be a sublass of Throwable
        No exception of type notAdultException can be thrown; an exception type must be a sublass of Throwable

        at Exception.Exception.main(Exception.java:44)
```

Comment: You need `extends java.lang.Exception`.

Comment: Using java programming conventions, packages use entirely lower case letters. Classes start with an upper case letter and use cammelCase (NotAdultException). Variables and methods start with a lower case letter and use cammelCase (age). Also, please paste text rather than images.

Comment: Adding a couple of more tips here:
1. Your `t` variable doesn't make much sense. It's generally accepted to have `e`, `ex`, etc. (coming from the word exception)
2. There's not much reason to use exceptions in this specific case. You can just check if `age < 18` and execute the code for a minor/adult there. This will help performance out.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica sorry but i thought images be easier to clear the error

Comment: @pitaya4 i know i just practice on Exception handel

Comment: @hev1 No he doesn't. `java.lang` is imported by default. What he needs to do is not have his own class called `Exception`, and change the name of his package.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne I should have phrased that better as "You can use".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have a class named `Exception` in the same package, so you will need to qualify access to `java.lang.Exception`. <sup>[Demo](https://ideone.com/AwmhnM)</sup>

```
public class notAdultException extends java.lang.Exception {
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "you are not adult";
    }
}
```

As a side note, you should always follow the [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) e.g. the name of your class should be `NotAdultException` instead of `notAdultException` and the name of your package should be something like `my.exceptions`.

Comment: Also: please do NOT name your classes or packages the same names as well known Java classes, esp. ones in `java.lang`.  You mess everything up when you overload the names of these classes.  `Exception` is a terrible name for both a class and a package.

Comment: i created a new project has a new name and did not work too but it work when i extend java.lang.Exception

Comment: @HagerKhaled No problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class notAdultException extends Exception {
 
    public notAdultException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to import java.lang.Exception (or use the full qualifier as mentioned above.)